# Trouble parsing JSON with Swift using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am new to swift and I am trying to parse some simple JSON data I am retrieving from a private API that I have.  I am using the SwiftJSON library.

No matter what I do I cannot assign the variable "videoUploadId" with the value of "video_upload_id" coming from the JSON response.  I hope i provided enough info to get some help.   Thanks

Here is a segment of the code

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    // Success
                    let statusCode = (response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                    println("Status Code: \(statusCode)\r\n")

                    println("Response: \(response)\r\n")

                    println("Data: \(data)\r\n")

                    let dataContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    println("UTF8 Data: \(dataContent)\r\n")

                    let json = JSON(dataContent)

                    if let videoUploadId = json["video_upload_id"].int {

                        println("Video Upload ID (Dict: int): \(videoUploadId)")
                    }

                    else if let videoUploadId = json["video_upload_id"].string {

                        println("Video Upload ID (Dict: string): \(videoUploadId)")
                    }

                    else if let videoUploadId = json[0].int {

                        println("Video Upload ID (Array: int): \(videoUploadId)")
                    }

                    else if let videoUploadId = json[0].string {

                        println("Video Upload ID (Array: string): \(videoUploadId)")

                    }


                    else {
                        println(json["video_upload_id"].error)
                    }


                }
                else {
                    // Failure
                    println("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }
            })
            task.resume()
```

This is what I am receiving from my console:

Login Response: HTTP 200
Status Code: 201

Response:  { URL: https://*/*/videos/uploads/ } { status code: 201, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 24;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sun, 25 Jan 2015 01:02:42 GMT";
    Location = "https://*/*/videos/uploads/";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
    "Set-Cookie" = "session=eyJzZXNzaW9uX3Rva2VuIjp7IiBiIjoiUzAxWGFYRnlVVGM1YjBsa1kxWkJiV2xrYVZwcFZXdDFiR0ZLYW5GQ1VqRjFjbk5GIn19.B6XSMg.HXatQ76ZFaoZEQsnNu1BgsVECKA; HttpOnly; Path=/";
} }

Data: <7b227669 64656f5f 75706c6f 61645f69 64223a20 3736307d>

UTF8 Data: {"video_upload_id": 760}

Optional(Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 "Dictionary["video_upload_id"] failure, It is not an dictionary" UserInfo=0x170238620 {NSLocalizedDescription=Dictionary["video_upload_id"] failure, It is not an dictionary})

As you can see from the code and console output, I am attempting to set the variable in several different ways all of which seem to fail. I am receiving the error "Dictionary["video_upload_id"] failure, It is not an dictionary"  I even tried prepending "[" and appending "]" to try to see if its a formatting issue.

Any clues?

Answer (score 11):

You are doing the initialization wrong. You should use:

```
let json = JSON(data:data) // data is NSData!
```

Converting NSData to NSString is not necessary, and somehow wrong for this. SwiftyJSON can only be initialized with NSData or Swift object.

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'Data'` I face this issue when change code with above

Comment: This is answered four years ago. Swift has changed significantly since then. I suggest to ignore this answer now.