# JSON parsing in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, json, swift, macos, swift2

Looking for a way to parse this JSON and save the firstnames in an array :

```
[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

I am basically looking for a code that works without even SwiftyJSON and similar things.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132173/trouble-parsing-json-with-swift-using-swiftyjson

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am not looking into using SwiftyJSON and similar libraries .

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
let string = "[{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},{\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"}, {\"firstName\":\"Peter\",\"lastName\":\"Jones\"}]"

if let jsonData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
  do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    let firstNameArray = json.map {$0["firstName"]!}
    print(firstNameArray)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use backslashes in string ?

Comment: The backslashes are just for escaping the double quotes in a literal string. They are ignored while processing the string.

Comment: What if I want to load it from a file ? I don't want to edit the whole JSON

Comment: Don't worry about the backslashes. They appear only in literal strings to distinguish an inline double quote from a begin/end double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at SwiftyJSON.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

This is an easy way to parse a JSON file with minimum effort.

It is easily installed using CocoaPods. If you don't know CocoaPods I recommend that you wrap your head around this as it will be an immensely powerful tool to know during your swift programming career.

I hope I've put you on the right path.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11816958)

Comment: Okay thanks I didn't know that, I'll do so next time I answer. 

Comment: @Dijkgraaf This is not a link-only answer.

Comment: @Rob If you were to edit out the fluff, then all that is left is the link to github.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf No, there is still useful information in the answer without the hyperlink